# "Mr. Smith, John" or "Smith, Mr. John" Title location in reversed name

Tags: british-english, names

When writing a name in reverse order (following the commonly used [Last Name], [First Name] [Middle Name(s)] format) where is the most appropriate place to put the title?

For example, is it *Mr. Smith, John* or *Smith, Mr. John*?

I'm particularly confused about this since I know that a title like "Mr." or "Ms." is appropriate for both the first and last name. For example, both "Mr. John" and "Mr. Smith" are correct.

**Edit:** For context, this is for a list of teacher names at a high school. It will be included in various publications such as newsletters and timetables.

Comment: *Mr.* is pretty much the default for men and usually doesn't need to be included when using the "*lastname, firstname*" format.  But when the title is "Dr." it's "lastname, firstname, Dr."  and so if I were being forced to include "Mr." I'd put it at the end  as well.

Comment: Whilst you aren't developing code I would suggest you read this page as too many people assume names are simple.  https://www.google.co.uk/amp/s/shinesolutions.com/2018/01/08/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names-with-examples/amp/

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the particular style guide you are using—and where exactly these names are appearing.

For example, the *MLA Handbook* (8th ed.), says:

> **1.1.2 TITLES OF AUTHORS**
>
> If the name of the author of a source you consulted is given in the source with a title—such as *Dr.*, *Saint*, or *Sir*—generally omit the title in the works-cited list. Similarly, a title should usually not be included when the name is mentioned in the text discussion.
>
> Augustine (not Saint Augustine)
>       Samuel Johnson (not Dr. Johnson)
>       Philip Sidney (not Sir Philip Sidney)

Social titles are not used.

---

*The Chicago Manual of Style* (17th ed.), 16.40, also says to drop titles from names in indexes:

> Academic titles such as *Prof.* and *Dr.*, used before a name, are not retained in indexing, nor are abbreviations of degrees such as *PhD* or *MD.*

Similarly, social titles are not used.

However, *Chicago* does say this in 16.41:

> Abbreviations such as *Jr.* are retained in indexing but are placed after the given name and preceded by a comma . . .
>
> King, Martin Luther, Jr.
>       Stevenson, Adlai E., III

---

So, no titles of any kind are suggested by these style guides (Aside from *Jr.* and so on.) Other style guides may give other guidance.

If using these titles in a different context, and without a using a particular style guide, then the style would be up to you.

Should you decide to use a title, I expect common usage would put it at the end of the name, after a comma: *Last, First, Title*. (It would be particularly confusing for the presentation of sorted lists if the title were put first.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jason, I would up-vote it but I don't have the rep. Anyway the context in my particular case is for a list of teachers (some are doctors). The main reason the school wants to include titles is because most students address their teachers as "Mr/Ms. [Surname]." So in this situation I'm not sure if simply dropping the title is the best option, however using the Last, First, Title format might be an idea

Comment: I upvoted Jason Bassford's clear Answer yet I suggest Last, Title First trumps Last, First, Title… though the second comma makes a big difference.

*Webster's Dictionary* and *Debrett's Correct Form* are great references for such questions.